# What method should i use for this collision or how can i calculate it?

Tags: c#, xna

Hi i have problem with one collision. I trying to make sword swing collision.
My character turns with face to the mouse and when i click in front of his face will sword swing.
What is best way to make collision here? Something easiest possible and good for performance.

[Picture](https://screenshooter.blob.core.windows.net/engine4files/rabzigyezqrjsnevgwtfzyrfurfgtbrhdrchrxaoycfidcmiwyqqauativfqbskxyjfakxeiwehwtjbrfwkulbgirjyvsjngrhkuwlxzuhuwndzztnlehqmxcxjbyiqm)

Comment: it would help if you could show some code.

Comment: my code is really messy i don't know if that code help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not give you code, but could give you guidelines.

- check if your are swinging weapon, some boolean (true/false)
- rotate red dot (box) in direction of player
- check if red dot (box) colide with enemy box (blue) if boolean is true

[image]

hint: position of red box

```
X = cos(playerAngle) * weaponLength + player.Postion.X;
Y = sin(playerAngle) * weaponLength + player.Position.Y;
```

EDIT:
those red dots with above code will follow circle around player. By this player swing will collide only by facing enemy (blue). I have put green enemy, and if you wish to hit him you will have to turn your player.

[image]

Comment: Actually the red dot is rectangle which i made and i made collision with red dot, but i think it's not enough with comparison to the swing texture. Maybe if there is way to do like 3 dot then it will be okay. Like this blue dots in this pic.
[Picture](https://screenshooter.blob.core.windows.net/engine4files/jmpyyqnelwaxogxugbzvslqseymxubyolzjbgwccpmgamfixtnjjfugxwxuadqjjxmmoxwokyxfffqfyppdgroiqtlfjccyzdwcz).

Comment: i thought that red dot is most distanced point of swinging weapon.... anyway i would go that way, first with one dot (red) that collide enemy (blue). and if not enough, then will add 2 more dots +- few degrees based on playerAngle. i put some update image how i see that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Davor it helped me do it with 4 red dot. Like in this picture. I think it's enough for swing collison.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/WWWkO.jpg